# Modifying standalone Jar permissions for multiple drives

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, file-permissions, user-permissions

I have a standalone Jar created with intellij and it opens/runs perfectly fine. (And runs peachily within the IDE)

However when the individual JAR is executed and is then required to fetch data from P:\ or Z:\ the application simply hangs or acts like it is trying to grab the information from the specific drive.

Here is my question: Do I have to set drive access within the JAR? If so, where and how? :)

Comment: probably that the user is different and does not have these drives mapped.

Comment: As Scary Wombat wrote, or the user does not have permission to read from those drives.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm simply running the created jar from my user account which has permission to read/write but I did have to type in my credentials to gain me access..